# Javascript arrays into one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array `articles` that has arrays `results`. I am attempting to combine all these results into one array without the `results` for example:

```
const articles = [{ "id": 203, "title": "testing"}, {"id": 213,"title": "new title"}, { "id": 1, "title": "one"}, {"id": 2,"title": "two"}, { "id": 32, "title": "test article"}, {"id": 62,"title": "title test"}]
```

I've attempted to achieve this by mapping `articles` but the return result are still separate arrays instead of 1 array of objects. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code snippet:

```js
const articles = [{results: [{ "id": 203, "title": "testing"}, {"id": 213,"title": "new title"}]}, {results: [{ "id": 1, "title": "one"}, {"id": 2,"title": "two"}]}, {results: [{"id": 62,"title": "title test"}]} ]



let mappedArticles = articles.map(article => {
    return article.results
})
console.log(mappedArticles)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const articles = [{results: [{ "id": 203, "title": "testing"}, {"id": 213,"title": "new title"}]}, {results: [{ "id": 1, "title": "one"}, {"id": 2,"title": "two"}]}, {results: [{"id": 62,"title": "title test"}]} ]

let mappedArticles = articles.flatMap(article => article.results)
console.log(mappedArticles)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case `flatMap` is not supported by your environment, there is another way to achieve it, although a bit more verbose and non-trivial, which uses the [concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) method of the Array prototype:

```js
const articles = [{results: [{ "id": 203, "title": "testing"}, {"id": 213,"title": "new title"}]}, {results: [{ "id": 1, "title": "one"}, {"id": 2,"title": "two"}]}, {results: [{"id": 62,"title": "title test"}]} ]

const mappedArticles = articles.reduce((acc, article) => acc.concat(article.results), []);

console.log(mappedArticles);
```